# Symfony generate slug for entity if specific symbol

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity skill and have field slug from field skill and when I create skill and write C++ have slug=c OR if create C. - have slug=c OR when create C# still have slug=c. I think in Gedmo have something regular expression. Maybe who know how overwrite Gedmo slug or hot to fix this problem ?

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Skills.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="code_directory_skills")
 */
 class Skill
 {
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Expose()
 * @Groups({"for_skill_by_id", "for_all_skills", "for_all_skills_extended"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="skill", type="string", length=255)
 * @Expose()
 * @Groups({"for_skill_by_id", "for_all_skills", "for_all_skills_extended"})
 */
private $skill;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"skill"}, updatable=true)
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", nullable=false)
 * @Groups({"for_skill_by_id", "for_all_skills", "for_all_skills_extended"})
 * @Expose()
 */
protected $slug;
```

I create listener

```
namespace Artel\ProfileBundle\Listener;

use Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener as BaseSluggableListener;

class SluggableListener extends BaseSluggableListener
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->setTransliterator(array('\Artel\ProfileBundle\Util\Transliterator', 'transliterate'));
}
}
```

and create translator in $text I have C++ then in

```
Urlizer::urlize($text, $separator) //have have C
```

class:

```
use Gedmo\Sluggable\Util\Urlizer;

class Transliterator
{
public static function transliterate($text, $separator = '-')
{
    $text = Urlizer::unaccent($text);
    return Urlizer::urlize($text, $separator);
}
}
```

I change

```
class Transliterator
{
public static function transliterate($text, $separator = '-')
{
    $text = Urlizer::unaccent($text);

    return $text; //have C++
}
}
```

but in DB still have only slug=c

and config this extension:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
class:
    sluggable: Artel\ProfileBundle\Listener\SluggableListener
default_locale: "%locale%"
orm:
    default:
        timestampable: true
        sluggable:     true
        softdeleteable: true
```

How in Transliterator enable specific symbol for sluggable ? Who know ? When debug twice enters шт сдфыы Transliterator

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own listener and decide which policy you want to apply for slugs. See belows link.

https://github.com/Guite/MostGenerator/issues/241

In the `Translator::translate` you can define your policy.

Comment: Update my question. How in Transliterator enable specific symbol for sluggable ?